# MIPS: loading word in register $31

Tags: assembly, mips

this is my code:

```
jal next

next: lw $t0, 0x20($31)
         .
         .
         .
      sw $t0, 0x20($31)
```

I don't understand how this is loading word from register 31, if register 31 is the *return address* linked to *next* when *jal* was called.

What exactly is being loaded or saved onto register $t0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$t0` is loaded with the word from memory that is 0x20 bytes after the instruction word following the `jal` instruction.  If the `jal` was at address 0x80004000, `$t0` would be loaded with the contents of address 0x80004000 + 0x4 + 0x20 = 0x80004024.

This is not a useful coding technique, and it may crash your program on some MIPS implementations that implement *execute-only* .text segments, which cannot be read or written.

Answer (score 1):

Register `$31` can be used in a `lw` instruction just as any other general purpose register.
In this case, `$31` will hold the address of the next instruction after the issued `jal`.

Therefore `lw $t0, 0x20($31)` will load in $t0 the contents of the word located 32 bytes after the address of the next instruction which issued the `jal`.

Usually the loaded value can be interpreted as an instruction, i.e. it will be stored in the text segment and may be used to perform self-modifying code if you modify the contents of `$t0` and then `sw` it again to the same address.